# find the same words into different cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

find the common words in title of the books in Excel, the output like this :

```
   'book                              common                      user_id
    physics                           physics                         1
    Principles of plasma physics      physics,plasma                  2
    Fundamentals of plasma physics    fundamentals,plasma,physics     3
    Fundamentals of thermodynamics    fundamentals                    4
   '
```

Comment: can you be more specific? How would you define "common": when a word occurs in two or more titles? Also, do you have a list of words that should be excluded, like "of", "a", "the", "and", ...?

Comment: no i have a list of titles in excel ..I don't know how to find the common words! ...i don't have the list of words...:S what formulas can help me is there any way?

Comment: that would involve vba for sure. In any case, you would need to be more specific about the definition of "common" and preferably define a list of words to be excluded

Comment: Why is **of** not a common word ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Precisely. And would "the", "a", "in", etc. also not be listed? Which is why some further refinement by the OP is required.

Comment: well, the question is not very specific, but from the given example I was assuming @Fifo Hsn is only interested  in significant words

Comment: @NiH  Sometimes even tiny words are significant.

Comment: @NiH Ok, but define "significant" in such a way that Excel will understand you perfectly.

Comment: bcz I want  to find a specific word like(physic ,math,plasma,...)...i want to use them in a vba code to find at least two users have a book that have same word..like user_id :1 have a common book :physics and user_id:2 have a common book: physics...etc

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, XOR LX my definition of "significant" is not quite relevant here: what I'm suggesting is to create a function that takes a list of words to be excluded as one of the arguments. If the list is empty, that's fine and then all words will be treated as "significant"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's my shot at this problem. I am aware that the code is rather messy: I've been very sloppy with variable names, error handling and so on, but it gives you an idea of how it can be done. I've created a UDF `Common()` which takes 4 arguments:

- rngText: a reference to a single cell containing the text (in your case book) you want to comare
- compareList: a range of cells with which to compare the first argument
- minOccurences (optional): this is the definition of the minimum number of occurences a word should have to be considered "common". The default vanue is 2
- exclusionList (optional): a range of cells containing text that should be excluded (e.g. words like "a", "of", ...)

So for example, if you have your titles in A2:A7 and your exclusion list in E2:E3, you could use the formula `= Common( A2, $A$2:$A$7, , $E$2:$E$3 )`in cell B2 and copy down to B7.

```
Option Explicit

Function Common(rngText As Range, compareList As Range, _
    Optional minOccurences As Integer = 2, Optional exclusionList As Range) As Variant

    'Check if an exclusion list is provided
    Dim exclusionListProvided As Boolean
    If Not (exclusionList Is Nothing) Then
        exclusionListProvided = True
    Else
        exclusionListProvided = False
    End If

    'Check the argments
    Dim returnError As Boolean
    If IsDate(rngText.Value) Or IsNumeric(rngText.Value) Or IsError(rngText.Value) Then 'first argument should refer to a cell containing text
       returnError = True
    ElseIf minOccurences < 2 Then   'Function should check for at least 2 occurences
        returnError = True
    ElseIf (compareList.Columns.Count > 1 And compareList.Rows.Count > 1) Then  'compareList should be one-dimensional
        returnError = True
    ElseIf exclusionListProvided Then
        If (exclusionList.Columns.Count > 1 And exclusionList.Rows.Count > 1) Then  'exclusionList should be one-dimensional
            returnError = True
        End If
    Else
        returnError = False
    End If

    'Return an error if one of the arguments is unexpected
    If returnError Then
        Common = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Else
        Dim text As String
        text = rngText.Value

        'split text into an array of words
        Dim words() As String
        words = fullSplit(text)

        'convert exclusionlist and compareList to arrays
        Dim arrExclude()
        If exclusionListProvided Then
            arrExclude() = rangeToStringArray(exclusionList)
        End If
        Dim arrCompare()
        arrCompare() = rangeToStringArray(compareList)

        Dim strCommon As String
        'loop through words in text
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim nOccurences As Integer
        Dim excluded As Boolean
        Dim compareWords() As String

        For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
            'check if word is in exclusion list
            excluded = False
            If exclusionListProvided Then
                For j = LBound(arrExclude) To UBound(arrExclude)
                    compareWords = fullSplit(arrExclude(j))
                    For k = LBound(compareWords) To UBound(compareWords)
                        If compareWords(k) = words(i) Then
                            excluded = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next k
                    If excluded Then Exit For
                Next j
            End If

            'count the number of occurences of the word in the compare list
            If Not excluded Then
                nOccurences = 0
                For j = LBound(arrCompare) To UBound(arrCompare)
                    compareWords = fullSplit(arrCompare(j))
                    For k = LBound(compareWords) To UBound(compareWords)
                        If LCase(compareWords(k)) = LCase(words(i)) Then
                            nOccurences = nOccurences + 1
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next k
                Next j
                If nOccurences >= minOccurences Then
                    If Not strCommon = "" Then
                        strCommon = strCommon & ", "
                    End If
                    strCommon = strCommon & LCase(words(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        Common = strCommon
    End If


End Function

'split text by using a list of delimiters
Function fullSplit(text As Variant)
    'define list of delimiters
    Dim delimiters()
    delimiters = Array(" ", ",", ".", ";", "?", "!")

    'unique delimiter is the first one from the list
    Dim uniqueDelimiter As String
    uniqueDelimiter = delimiters(0)

    'replace all delimiters in the text by the unique delimiter
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(delimiters) + 1 To UBound(delimiters)
        Replace text, delimiters(i), uniqueDelimiter
    Next i

    'split the text by using the unique delimiter
    fullSplit = SplitText(text, uniqueDelimiter)

End Function

'split text by using a single delimiter
Function SplitText(text As Variant, delimiter As String)
    'split the text in substrings on each occurence of the delimiter
    Dim tempArray() As String
    tempArray = Split(text, delimiter)

    'remove empty substrings
    Dim LastNonEmpty As Integer
    LastNonEmpty = -1
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(tempArray) To UBound(tempArray)
        If tempArray(i) <> "" Then
            LastNonEmpty = LastNonEmpty + 1
            tempArray(LastNonEmpty) = tempArray(i)
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve tempArray(0 To LastNonEmpty)

    SplitText = tempArray
End Function

'check if two arrays share a least one element
Function sharedElements(array1() As Variant, array2() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    For i = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1)
        For j = LBound(array2) To UBound(array2)
            If array1(i) = array2(j) Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If found = True Then Exit For
    Next i

    sharedElements = found
End Function

'converts a range to an array of strings, omitting all non-text cells
Function rangeToStringArray(myRange As Range)
    Dim myArray()
    Dim arraySize As Integer
    arraySize = 0

    Dim c As Object
    For Each c In myRange
        If IsDate(c.Value) = False And IsNumeric(c.Value) = False And IsError(c.Value) = False Then
            ReDim Preserve myArray(arraySize)
            myArray(arraySize) = c.Value
            arraySize = arraySize + 1
        End If
    Next

    rangeToStringArray = myArray
End Function
```