# Look up similar (but not exact same) data in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have several thousand names that I would like to reference to an HR report to 1. Give them a consistent name format and 2. Pull other data referenced to that name, etc.

The problem is that these names are user entered in my current data source. Meaning, they can be first, last; last, first; last first; or any other combination.

Names in the HR report are all similar format: Last,First Middleinitial, with that exact spacing.

Is there a way, I can look up names that are virtually identical to the origin data, but not in the same format?

[image]

Essentially, I need to find a way to pull in HRs: Saget,Bob R, into a column next to Original's: Saget, Bob, using only this data.

Thanks!

Comment: you will need some elaborate vba code for that if you can't count on the original data being in a certain order or format. I provided an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34828376/2923617) to a very related question. The code there will need quite some modifications, but it could put you on the right track.

Comment: I'd use a Fuzzy Matching solution.  Best one I've found is here:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/195635-fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.html